# ERROR ITMS-90283 with "Invalid 'com.apple.application-identifier' entitlement value" when submitting Mac Catalyst app

Tags: xcode, app-store, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to submit a Mac Catalyst app for the first time, but the upload keeps failing with this error message:

> ERROR ITMS-90283: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle maccatalyst.com.arlomedia.setlistmaker [maccatalyst.com.arlomedia.setlistmaker.pkg/Payload/SetListMaker.app] is invalid. [Invalid 'com.apple.application-identifier' entitlement value.] For more information, visit the macOS Developer Portal."

This happens if I manually or automatically sign the app. With manual signing, I have a new macOS App Store provisioning profile that I created as a Mac Catalyst profile using the associated iOS app ID. This shows as valid in the provisioning portal, and I can build (archive) the app just fine with this profile selected:

[image: Xcode signing settings]

When I go through the submission process in the Xcode organizer, I have to "Import" the provisioning profile every time (I downloaded the provisioning file, and just select the downloaded file here), which is odd:

[image]

But after I select the file, I can click its info icon and everything looks correct:

[image]

Then I proceed with the upload, and when the progress bar reaches the end, the error appears and the submission fails.

The error message indicates something is wrong with the application-identifier, but I've checked this everywhere I can find it and it looks correct. I'm using automatically derived bundle IDs, which prefixes "maccatalyst" onto my iOS bundle ID. In some places where this appears, the ID is also prefixed with the App ID Prefix from the apps Identifier record in the provisioning portal. The screen shot above shows the last letter of the App ID cut off, but I think that's just the display in Xcode; if I open the provisioning file, the full ID is listed.

I have another app I've been working on at the same time and I was able to submit it successfully. I opened the archived .app files for both projects and compared the embedded provisioning profiles, and the only differences are things I would expect, like the app name and export time. The application-identifers and bundle IDs are formatted the same way, with the correct app prefixes. I also compared the info.plist files for the two apps and didn't see any significant differences there, either. The other app also required me to select the profile during the submission process, so it seems like that's not a problem (although with my iOS submissions, the profile name appears there automatically).

When I turn on automatic signing, some upload steps are skipped, but I get the same error message at the end of the upload. If I use the Validate App button instead of the Distribute App button in the Xcode organizer, I go through the same steps and get the same error message.

I've compared the setup of the app IDs and profiles of both apps, the signing settings, the build settings, the App Information pages in iTunes Connect ... everything is set up the same way. Does anyone know what else I should check?

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet; I still haven't been able to submit the app. I contacted Apple Developer support and they said they forwarded the issue to engineering but didn't have a timeline for a response. I'll post an update if they come back with something useful.

Comment: I am trying for MAC application and not the Mac Catalyst, still I am getting same error. Please post the update.

Comment: Apple didn't help; they just sent me links to documentation, none of which addressed my issue. But I did find a solution and will post it as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work by giving up on the automatically derived "maccatalyst" bundle ID and using a custom bundle ID. Here are the steps I took:

1. In Xcode, turn off the "Derive Mac Catalyst Product Bundle Identifier" build setting.
2. Edit the "Product Bundle Identifier" build setting and add a separate bundle ID for the macOS platform. (screen shot 1)
3. In the iOS Provisioning Portal, edit the App ID for the associated iOS app and turn off the Mac Catalyst option.
4. Create a new App ID for the Mac version of the app, and enter the new macOS bundle ID.
5. Create new development and distribution profiles using the new App ID. When creating the profiles, these must be Mac Catalyst, not Mac, profiles. Xcode would only accept Mac Catalyst profiles when validating. (screen shot 2)
6. In App Store Connect, edit the macOS app record and change the bundle ID from the maccatalyst ID to the custom ID. This was still editable because I hadn't yet successfully uploaded a binary.

My new profiles now appear as Eligible on the Signing & Capabilities tab in Xcode, but they do not appear as options on the validation page when submitting. However, as with my original setup, I can click the Import Profile option there and select the file downloaded from the provisioning portal.

Note that this is the setup to use if you do not want Universal Purchase. If you do want that, you would need to use the same bundle ID as for the iOS app, and you might need to wait until Xcode 11.4 is released in order to submit the app with that setup. I'm not sure about that, but I am sure that you cannot submit apps with the Xcode 11.4 beta, because I tried it. (screen shot 3)

I didn't try automatic signing with the custom bundle ID setup. I think that would work because I think somehow the problem was related to the automatically derived bundle ID. That is basically deprecated with the upcoming Xcode 11.4 and Universal Purchase capability, so I suspect that a change on Apple's end has broken the validation of that style of bundle ID, perhaps only in limited cases that affected my app due to some factor that neither I nor Apple were able to identify.

*Custom bundle ID settings:*
[image: Custom bundle ID settings]

*"Profile is not a 'Mac Catalyst App Store' profile":*
[image: "Profile is not a 'Mac Catalyst App Store' profile"]

*Cannot submit from Xcode beta:*
[image: Cannot submit from Xcode beta]

Comment: Xcode 11.4 is released but there's a problem when you want to submit your app with the same bundle id for universal purchase: The error is Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle xxx [xxx.pkg/Payload/xxx.app] is invalid. [Invalid 'com.apple.application-identifier' entitlement value.] For more information, visit the macOS Developer Portal.. :( Any recommendations?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. My goal was to not use Universal Purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I found this document:

[Technical Q&A QA1710: Why do I get an "Invalid application-identifier Entitlement" error?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1710/_index.html)

It states:

> In modern versions of Xcode, you don't need to supply a value for this entitlement yourself, so the error can be avoided by simply removing the application identifier entitlement from your custom Entitlements.plist.
>
> Xcode builds the application identifier entitlement for you based on the Bundle Identifier property defined in your Xcode project's Target > Info tab, so setting the correct Bundle Identifier in Xcode is imperative.

I don't have either of those problems, but maybe it will help someone else receiving this error.